# The intl example does not work for me

Tags: php, date, calendar, intl

Running below example from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.parse.php) returns false for me (other examples in this page have the same issue). Is it a bug?

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'America/Los_Angeles',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN
);
echo 'First parsed output is ' . $fmt->parse('Wednesday, December 20, 1989 4:00:00 PM PT');


echo $fmt->getErrorMessage(); // return: U_PARSE_ERROR
```

It seems `parse` method need `format` parameter of  `IntlDateFormatter` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set pattern using [setPattern](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.setpattern.php) that gets patterns as said [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime).

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem here. 
In my case the php internationalization extension was not installed:

sudo apt-get install php5-intl